# IBM MobileFirst - Login form database

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

Good morning,

Do you know any example or can you provide me with a link that explains the best possible way to create a login screen for validation on the server side, through the access to a database in mobile first platform studio (in this case is informix, but I guess that any other conector could do, I would just have to change the settings)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This Forum is not used for general discussion.

However, if you would like to know more about IBM MFP [Getting started](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started/) will help you.

A sample for Login screen and Server side validation will help you, follow this [Guide](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/authentication-security/adapter-based-authentication/)

I will recommend you to invest some time in google to find the resources.

Comment: @Eladerezador mark as answered if it solve your problem